# Local persistent variables in NodeJS WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to make persistent variable `player` for each WebSocket connection like this:

```
Server.on('request', function(request) {
    const WSCon = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    var player = "none";
    WSCon.on('message', function(message) {
        if (data.action == 0) HandleRoomEnter(player);
        if (data.action == 1) HandleReadyness(player);
    });
});

function HandleRoomEnter(player) {
    player = "Conan";
    console.log("setting: "+player);
}
function HandleReadyness(player) {
    console.log("getting: "+player);
}
```

However, my output is:

```
setting: Conan
getting: none
```

Where is the problem?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way of doing this:

```
Server.on('request', function(request) {
    const WSCon = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    let player = "none";
    function HandleRoomEnter(player) {
        player = "Conan";
        console.log("setting: "+player);
    }
    function HandleReadyness(player) {
        console.log("getting: "+player);
    }

    WSCon.on('message', function(message) {
        if (data.action == 0) HandleRoomEnter(player);
        if (data.action == 1) HandleReadyness(player);
    });
});
```

Also *please* use let or const instead of var.

Comment: Thank you, it is not exactly the correct way, but it help me to find it. I had to remove the "player" parameters from the functions. Instead of "HandleRoomEnter(player)" -> "HandleRoomEnter()". After that, it worked. Thank you